# How can I manually infer the instance const :: a -> a -> a

Tags: haskell, types, quantifiers

Haskell type variables are implicitly quantified. The keywords `forall` appear after `::`.

For example, `const` type signature

```hs
const :: a -> b -> a
```

is written as:

```hs
const :: forall a b. a -> b -> a
```

My question is: how can I validly infer the signature

```
const :: forall a. a -> a -> a
```

from that definition. I tried using concepts I learned from first-order logic like *Universal Elimination* but couldn't justify from a theoretic standpoint.

Of course, it makes sense since nothing precludes `b` being the same as `a`.

Why I couldn't justify using that inference rule ? Because I can't use elimination on that second quantifier since variables would clash.  I can't instantiate `b` with `a`.

Comment: Thank you @Micha Wiedenmann. Could you tell me which Natural Deduction system allows using a bound variable in an Universal Elimination inference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

```
(1) const :: forall a b. a -> b -> a

(2) const :: forall a. a -> a -> a
```

You can't **infer** (2) from (1); if you could that would imply that `const` *always* has a type fitting `forall a. a -> a -> a` (and it just wasn't obvious in (1) because we hadn't applied enough inference steps yet). But I can obviously use `const` in situations like `const True 'a'`, where `const` has type `Bool -> Char -> Bool`.

What you can do is realise that (2) is an *instantiation* of (1). `b` is not the same as `a` **in general**, but (as you said) there is nothing stopping `b` from being the same thing as `a` in any one particular usage. So from a context where `const` is used you may be able to infer **that particular usage** has type `forall a. a -> a -> a`. For example, that happens in:

```
silly :: forall a. a -> a
silly x = const x x
```

You can also tell from `const :: forall a b. a -> b -> a` alone that if you **choose** to instantiate `b` to be the same as `a` you get `const :: forall a -> a -> a`. We always have that as an option because the type promised to be valid for **all** possible types `b`, which includes the subset of possibilities where we always choose the same thing for `b` as we do for `a`.

To do that we do simply replace the `b`s with `a`s (within the scope of the quantifier that we're instantiating, but here that's the whole expression). You expressed doubt that you could do this because the variables would clash, but instantiating one variable to be the same as the other is the **point** of what we're doing here. It's not the same as simply renaming variables and *accidentally* changing the expression by giving variables the same name that were supposed to be distinct; here we are making the deliberate choice to examine the special case when they are *not* distinct.

But there is no chain of pure inference from `const :: forall a -> b -> a` alone (without any context of where it is used) to `const :: forall a. a -> a -> a`, because when you make that change you are weakening/specialising `const`; you're choosing to limit it to a subtype of its most general type. Inference rules won't get you from (1) to (2) without you adding the additional information that you are choosing to limit `b` to be the same as `a`. (In Haskelly terms, this would be an additional `a ~ b` constraint)

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you so much. How do you replace b's with a's? `a` is bound to the outermost quantifier.

Comment: @F.Zer I suppose if you want to get that picky, you go via a step where you rewrite `forall a b. a -> b -> a` to `forall b a. a -> b -> a`, because those two expressions are equivalent. But when I'm reasoning I usually just think of the variables in a single `forall` as an unordered set, so I don't care about that step. Only when you start doing explicit `TypeApplications` does it actually matter. And many of the `forall`s are implicit anyway, which means the exact order the variables are quantified is invisible anyway. So 90% of the time I treat them as not having an order at all.

Comment: Thank you ! Now it is clearer ! You are using `forall b a. a -> b -> a`. Can use eliminate the outermost quantifier using as instance variable a bound variable ? In this case, you would be using `a`. Could you tell me which Natural Deduction system you are thinking of ?

Comment: @F.Zer TBH, I am now thinking my answer isn't really what you want. I wrote it talking about how Haskell works *as a programming language*; you seem to be more interested in the details of a formal theory. Haskell occasionally does things that are theoretically wonky for practical programming reasons, and even in areas where it *has* perfect theoretical basis most Haskellers think and reason about Haskell using informal principles that may be different.

Comment: @F.Zer However, if I try to approach your question more theoretically, I suppose what I am doing is really a formalised equivalent of "since I can choose `a` and `b` freely, I could for any given type `c` choose them both to be `c`". So I'm really getting `forall c. c -> c -> c` (which I am free to rename `a` so it looks like I "set `b` to `a`). Approached that way I'm actually applying *both* quantifiers, and neither of them is being applied to the variable bound by the other, rather to a new variable I'm introducing to stand for any concrete type I like.

Answer (score 0):

The following started as comments and was moved here.

> Because I can't use elimination on that second quantifier since variables would clash.

I think here you are simply wrong. You can in fact use elimination and the clash of variables is irrelevant for Universal Elimination. [From what I learned from the source below it seems to be the case that sometimes a clash is relevant and sometimes it is not.]

> Could you tell me which Natural Deduction system allows using a bound variable in an Universal Elimination inference?

[Chapter 8 of Stanford Introduction to Logic](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/notes/chapter_08.html) defines *Universal Elimination (UE)*
as

```
∀ν.φ[ν]
------------
φ[τ]
where τ is substitutable for ν in φ
```

and

> We say that a term τ is free for a variable ν in a sentence φ if and only if no free occurrence of ν occurs within the scope of a quantifier of some variable in τ.

With this and *Universal Introduction (UI)* I would argue

```
∀a.∀b.a⇒(b⇒a)
-------------- UE, a is free for a in ∀b.a⇒(b⇒a).
∀b.a⇒(b⇒a)
-------------- UE, a is free for b in a⇒(b⇒a).
a⇒(a⇒a)
-------------- UI, a does not occur free in both a⇒(a⇒a) and
∀a.a⇒(a⇒a)       an active assumption. I am not sure about this.
```

This leaves the claims that `a is free for a in ∀b.a⇒(b⇒a)`, etc.

```
a is free for a in ∀b.a⇒(b⇒a) 
⇔
no free occurrence of a occurs within the scope of a quantifier of some variable in a
```

There is no quantifier of `a` in `∀b.a⇒(b⇒a)`, therefore `a` does not occur free within the scope of (the non existing) quantifier of `a` in `∀b.a⇒(b⇒a)`.

Comment: Thanks to you for giving a detailed answer !

Comment: I appreciate you gave the link to the system. I am not convinced. First, I think that system is assuming a non-empty system. I am used to systems that could work in an empty domain. Second, what's the point of using a dummy variable bound by the quantifier to instantiate an universal claim ?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know enough to answer your questions. Maybe ["Does natural deduction require a non-empty set of premises?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930923) is helpful. I am not sure I got your second part. I don't really understand the difference between `a⇒(a⇒a)` and `∀a.a⇒(a⇒a)` but the later probably corresponds to `const :: a->a->a`.

Comment: May I take the chance and ask you something in return? I am unclear about Universal Introduction. What is meant by "an active assumption" in the linked page in the paragraph about UI?

Comment: Thank you for getting back. I am not a logic expert, but from what I understand, if a semantic allows empty structures then you could end up proving something like ∀x ( Q(x) ) ⇒ ∃x ( Q(x) ). This is actually wrong for semantics that allow empty domains.

Comment: About "active assumption" (or undischarged assumption), I'm not familiar with that system. Nevertheless, an assumption is discharged when the subproof is closed. It is undischarged while the subproof is still active.

Comment: In the systems I have worked with, in order to use certain rules, you should make "additional assumptions". For example, Implication Introduction. To prove A => B, you assume A and reach B, at which point you can apply ->I and discharge A (it's not an active assumption anymore).

Comment: I would suggest you look into this post. It has an excellent Fitch style ND system: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681857/predicate-logic-how-do-you-self-check-the-logical-structure-of-your-own-argumen/1684204#1684204

Comment: Also, Language, Proof and Logic book is very good. Feel free to ask further questions.